# signalR groups - connecting/disconnecting and sending - am I missing something?

Tags: signalr

very new to signalR, and have rolled up a very simple app that will take questions for moderation at conferences (felt like a straight forward use case)

I have 2 hubs at the moment:
- Question (for asking questions)
- Speaker (these should receive questions and allow moderation, but that will come later)

Solution lives at https://github.com/terrybrown/InterASK

After watching a video (by David Fowler/Damian Edwards) (http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Damian-Edwards-and-David-Fowler-Demonstrate-SignalR)

and another that I can't find the URL for atm, I thought I'd go with 'groups' as the concept to keep messages flowing to the right people.

I implemented IConnected, IDisconnect as I'd seen in one of the videos, and upon debugging I can see Connect fire (and on reload I can see disconnect fire), but it seems nothing I do adds a person to a group.

The signalR documentation suggests "Groups are not persisted on the server so applications are responsible for keeping track of what connections are in what groups so things like group count can be achieved" which I guess is telling me that I need to keep some method (static or otherwise?) of tracking who is in a group?

Certainly I don't seem able to send to groups currently, though I have no problem distributing to anyone currently connected to the app and implementing the same JS method (2 machines on the same page).

I suspect I'm just missing something - I read a few of the other questions on here, but none of them seem to mention IConnected/IDisconnect, which tells me these are either new (and nobody is using them) or that they're old (and nobody is using them).

I know this could be considered a subjective question, though what I'm looking for is just a simple means of managing the groups so that I can do what I want to - send a question from one hub, and have people connected to a different hub receive it - groups felt the cleanest solution for this?

Many thanks folks.
Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to understand, which groups a logical connection (user if you will) is in is something you the application writer is responsible for maintaining across network disconnects/reconnects. If you look at the way [JabbR](https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR) does this, it maintains the state of which "rooms" a user is in in its database. Upon reconnecting, a user's identity helps place the current connection back into the proper set of groups that represent the specific "rooms".

Comment: Thanks Drew - I assumed as much, but hoped I was missing the obvious - will grab the jabbr code and look at how they're handing group membership.

really is something I feel the documentation would gain from - I suspect it's the pain point of being a (relatively) early adopter though.